# Why doesn't my Python Function start when called upon?

Tags: python, function

Whenever I'm calling my start() function, after it's been declared, I get a error saying it doesn't exist. My complete code is below.

```
import random
import time
global monsters
monsters = ['Goblin','Orc','Knight','Unicorn','Black Bear','White Dragon','Black Dragon','Dark Knight','Undead Corpse']
global player_level
player_level = 1
global player_exp
global monster_level
monster_level = monster_determ_easy
player_exp = 0
player_exp_n = 10
global monster_attack
global player_attack
player_attack = random.randint(1,4) + player_level
global monster_levels
global monster_determ_easy
global monster_determ_medium
global monster_determ_hard
global monster_determ_epic
global attacks
global gold
gold = 0
attacks = ['Punch','Fireball']
monster_determ_easy = random.randint(1,3)
monster_levels_easy = player_level - monster_determ_easy

monster_determ_medium = random.randint(1,3)
monster_levels_medium = player_level + monster_determ_medium

monster_determ_hard = random.randint(3,5)
monster_levels_hard = player_level + monster_determ_hard

monster_determ_epic = random.randint(5,10)
monster_levels_epic = player_level + monster_determ_epic

monster_attack = monsters_levels + random.randint(1,3)

def start():
    if player_exp>=player_exp_n:
            player_level=player_level+1
            print "You've reached level ",player_level
            gold=gold+random.randint(1,15) + player_level
            print 'You were awared ',' gold!'
            start()
            command = raw_input(">")
    if command == "fight":
            player_attack = random.randint(1,4) + player_level
            monster_attack = monsters_levels + random.randint(1,3)
            choose_monster = random.choose(monsters)
            print 'You encounter a level ',monster_determ_easy,choose_monster,'.'
            time.sleep(1)
            print 'Prepare to fight!'
            strike = random.random()
            if strike>=0.5:
                if player_attack >= monster_attack:
                    print 'You slained the ',choose_monster,'!'
                    exp_choose = random.randint(1,5) + player_level
                    player_exp = player_exp + exp_choose
                    print 'You were awarded ',exp_choose,' XP!'
                    start()

start()
# This was just added
```

Comment: We all started somewhere, I guess.

Comment: `global` at module level does nothing.  It is meant to be used inside functions to mark names global inside this particular function.  (This is not an answer to your question.)

Comment: I know that, It's for future use as I expand the RPG.

Comment: delete all lines starting with `global`, they are pointless.

Comment: That won't solve my issue and as I said above, they are for future use.

Comment: a clear -1 for too many global variables....

Comment: @Sentinel: ... THAT'S why you'd downvote it?

Comment: @user578697: There are undefined variables, just run the code and read the traceback. If you don't understand what it says you can find an explanation on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Because the first if statement evaluates to false, so you never have the opportunity to set the command variable.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's only called from within itself.

Comment: YES, I know that. But try placing the start() at the bottom of the code from outside. It doesn't work./

Comment: Perhaps showing us how you call it would be helpful. You had said that your complete code was pasted, so I'd assumed that was your problem.

Comment: If the above code is in a module and you import it, you'll need to include the module name when you call it: `game.start()`.